# How can I test commands in Python? (Eclipse/PyDev)

Tags: python, eclipse, command-line, pydev

I just setup PyDev with Eclipse, but I'm a little confused. I thought that in the console I would be able to type certain commands such as print("Hello World") and directly observe the result without having to incorporate that in any sort of file.

The reason I would like this is because it would allow me to test functions real quick before using them in scripts, and I'm also following a tutorial which tells me to check if NumPy is installed by typing import NumPy in the command line.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be an [interactive console](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html) in PyDev.

Try `Ctrl+Alt+Enter` or `Cmd+Alt+Enter`.

Comment: That linked helped me, I figured it out. I needed to change a setting in the PyDev console. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Open up terminal and type python then it should load python shell then type
     import numpy

I have used pydev and find its easier just to use terminal to run small commands

Comment: I do this for R and should of thought of it. Great idea!

Comment: Even better, just make an alias for `python -i -c 'import numpy'`.

Comment: Both work. If you want to run something like a loop or something over several lines write a text file and save it as something like test.py and run that in the command window python environment. PyDev is good but I find that for conceptual testing just running things in terminal is better